# MYSQL update where value IS NULL also updating values that are not null

Tags: mysql

I needed to update a column so that NULL values became a default flag, 'N", in rows that also have a certain value in the 'division' columnn.
(The flag can be NULL if the 'division' column is certain other values)
Seemed easy enough....

```
UPDATE participation_criteria SET rfb_flag='N' WHERE division_id=2 AND rfb_flag IS NULL;
```

However,the first time this ran in dev and the first time it ran in test it replaced ALL flags for rows with division_id=2 to 'N" (not just the ones where rfb_flag was set to NULL). So if a row had  'Y" flag and division_id=2, it also was set to 'N".

This...

```
id | ....| division_id | rfb_flag
 3             2            NULL
 4             2            Y
 5             2            NULL
 6             2            Y
```

Became

```
id | ....| division_id | rfb_flag
 3             2            N
 4             2            N
 5             2            N
 6             2            N
```

**EDIT: This should not happen right?** *Problem is another dev on the team confirmed it, so I needed to try to recreate it*

BUT, if I go back into the data and add a NULL value to the flag column in one row and a 'Y' value for the flag in other and run the sql again, it leaves the 'Y' and only replaces the NULL.

So manually setting to this...

```
id | ....| division_id | rfb_flag
 3             2            NULL
 4             2            Y
 5             2            N
 6             2            N
```

And running again rightly became

```
id | ....| division_id | rfb_flag
 3             2            N
 4             2            Y
 5             2            N
 6             2            N
```

In other words, I'm having a hard time replicating the scenario on a small scale. Any tips?

Comment: Does someone have an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happened to me before. In my case what solved it is to do:

```
UPDATE participation_criteria SET rfb_flag='N' WHERE division_id=2 AND ISNULL(rfb_flag);
```

Hope it helps.